# how to generate config using jinja2 and a json file in python

Tags: python, json, jinja2

i have a json file `vlans.json` which contains the following

```
{"1": {"description": "default", "name": "default"}, "2": {"description": "ilo", "name": "ILO"}}
```

and based on this info i'm trying to generate a config using some jinja2 template that should generate an output like

```
#
vlan 1
 description default
 name default
#
vlan 2
 description ilo
 name ilo
#
```

any idea how the code for this one should look like?

so far i have this code, but nothing works...

```
from jinja2 import Template
import json

vlans_file = "vlans.json"

vlan_template = '''
vlan {{ vlans.id }}
 description {{ vlans.description }}
 name {{ vlans.name }}
 #
'''

with open(vlans_file) as json_file:
    vlans = json.load(json_file)
    for key in vlans:
        vlan_config = vlan_template.render(vlans)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made some progress

```
from jinja2 import Template
import json

vlans_file = "vlans.json"

with open(vlans_file) as json_file:
    vlans = json.load(json_file)

vlan_template = Template('''
{% for vlan in vlans %}
#
vlan {{ vlan }}
 description {{ value }}
#
{% endfor %}

''')

print(vlan_template.render(vlans = vlans))
```

and it prints

```
#
vlan 1
 description 
#

#
vlan 2
 description 
#
```

unfortunately i dunno how to get to the output below

```
#
vlan 1
 description default
 name default
#
vlan 2
 description ilo
 name ilo
#
```